# Export a list of customers who completed registration but haven't performed any action (no invoice, expense, withdrawal)

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

This is the full task :

`Export a list of customers who completed registration but haven't performed any action (no invoice, expense, withdrawal) last week (3-9 May)`

I need to create this type of SQL, but I don't know how to check for actions, what I did for now is

```
SELECT user FROM users_user 
WHERE completed_registration=False
AND date_joined BETWEEN '2021-05-03 00:00:00' AND '2021-05-29 00:00:00'
UNION
SELECT user FROM invoice_invoice;
```

Check for users who had completed the registration, check for the date, and then check the invoice. But as I check for invoice_invoice itself it's an empty table, why do I get one user when I launch this query? The completed_registration and the date fields which are in queryset right now are only for test.

[image]

Only users
[image]

This is when I check only for invoices
[image]

This is the structure:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Expense model:

```
class Merchant(BaseModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='merchants')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.company} {self.name}'


class Expense(Operation):
    category = models.CharField(choices=ExpenseCategories.get_choices(), default=ExpenseCategories.GENERAL.name,
                                db_index=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Merchant, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='expenses', blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=True, help_text='Only taxable amount. In cents')
    full_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0,
        blank=True,
        help_text='Full amount. Most of the time same as amount or bigger. In cents'
    )
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='expenses',
                                 default=settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE)
    description = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    is_taxable = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=True)
    from_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='Start date in case of aggregated bulk creation.')
    to_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='End date in case of aggregated bulk creation.')
    receipt_number = models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=255, help_text='Number from receipt.')
```

Invoice model:

```
class Invoice(Operation):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoices')
    number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    notes = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    payment_due = models.DateField()
    total = models.PositiveIntegerField(help_text='In cents', default=0)
    payment_status = models.CharField(choices=InvoiceStatuses.get_choices(), default=InvoiceStatuses.UNPAID,
                                      max_length=20)
    pdf = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='invoices/pdf', max_length=255)
    is_sent = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Is pdf invoice sent")
```

User model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None

    email = models.EmailField('email address', blank=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)

    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.ForeignKey(
        Language,
        default=settings.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/avatars', null=True, blank=True)
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company, related_name='users')
    active_company = models.OneToOneField(Company, null=True, related_name='active_user', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    agreement_text = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    agreement_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    personal_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='Field holds first and last names.', default='', blank=True)
    completed_registration = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    work_hours_from = models.TimeField(default=settings.DEFAULT_WORK_HOURS_FROM, null=True, blank=True)
    work_hours_until = models.TimeField(default=settings.DEFAULT_WORK_HOURS_UNTIL, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question
 Include the models you have made in Django.

Comment: Do you want an Raw SQL or Django `.filter()` Solution?

Comment: I need an Raw SQL

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `not exists`.  I would expect logic like this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users_user u
WHERE u.completed_registration AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM invoice_invoice i
                  WHERE i.user = u.user AND
                        i.invoice_date >= '2021-05-03' AND
                        i.invoice_date < '2021-05-10'
                 );
```

You would repeat this logic for each table where you want to check an action.  Also, it is not clear what date you want to use within the `invoice` table, so I made one up.

Comment: relation "invoice" does not exist LINE 5: FROM invoice i ^

Comment: Hey, can we continue in chat?